# Convergence of $\Gamma'(s)$ with pure imaginary number

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, gamma-function, complex-integration

$$\Phi(s) = \frac{\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1} \quad(-1<s<0), \quad a_k = \frac{2\pi k}{\ln 2}i \quad(k\neq 0) $$

Now that $a_k$ are pure imaginary poles, I wanna get

$$\lim_{s\to a_k}(s-a_k)\Phi(s)$$

Using l'Hopital,
$$\lim_{s\to a_k} \frac{\Gamma(a_k) +(s-a_k)\Gamma'(s)}{\ln 2}$$

Does $\Gamma'(a_k)$ converge so that the value is $\frac{\Gamma(a_k)}{\ln 2}$?

How to prove $\Gamma'(a_k) < \infty$ ??

Comment: $\Gamma$ is a meromorphic function with poles at nonpositive integers so it's derivative is analytic hence continuous everywhere else